# Are there any alternatives to C?

Tags: c, programming-languages

C++ is often touted as the evolution of C, which it is not. To draw an analogy for the kind of language I'm looking for:

- Perl, Python, Ruby, Groovy
- C++, D
- Java, C#
- C, Fortran, Modula-2?, Pascal?, Go?, Rust?

Do any proposed, or implemented languages fit in the same (enormous) niche as C, with the intention of being an alternative, while maintaining all the applicability to OS, high performance, embedded and other roles?

Comment: Where did you come up with these "evolutions"?

Comment: At least part of your premise is faulty. Python is not and has never been anything remotely like an evolution of Perl. In fact, it is nearly as old as Perl.

Comment: *Java -> C#*? Really?

Comment: They're to draw out the concept, I'm not saying they're replacements, just similar in feature sets and applicability.

Comment: Although this is highly subjective, the Zen of Python - "There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it" - seems to me to be a very deliberate evolution of Perl's "There is more than one way to do it".

Comment: I'm totally aware, but it completely replaces Perl. Anyway I've made the groups more set like, maybe now you can see what I'm referring to.

Comment: those 'evolutions' are just absurd and even insulting.  the c->c++ you're rejecting is far (_far_) more appropriate than any of yours

Comment: @Shabbyrobe: That phrase, which is widely-quoted yet almost completely irrelevant in practice, may have been coined in response to one aspect of Perl, but Python development began in the late 80s not long after the first versions of Perl were released. Python's most direct ancestor is probably ABC.

Comment: @Matt: In what way does it completely replace Perl? This sounds like "anything Perl can do, Python can do better", which is far from the truth.

Comment: It's stable equilibrium. Language vendors must enjoy talking to you. And you probably like the ever-expanding universe of Visual Studio. How about at least a Community wiki.

Comment: Well, two out of three are alphabetic progressions, I guess ...

Comment: Pascal, Fortran and Modula-2 seem to share the same space as C. Go seems to be the best for an alternative so far.

Comment: These comparisons seem okay to me. He didn't mention the comma representing evolutions anywhere, so I take them to represent sets... C++ and D are languages that try to bring OO to low level languages resulting in a convoluted monster. Python and Perl are dynamically typed languages, you can fit Ruby and Groovy in there too. Java and C# are statically typed managed languages, and both are made to run on a common binary platform. Blah Blah Blah insert "Perl is magically better than Python in some way so it doesn't completely suck" here.

Comment: So your favourite language sux. We're not going to force you to change.

Comment: @Matt: Pascal was designed as a very capable *teaching* language and is intentionally difficult to cheat with. Fortran is one of the first language that were ever written and is designed for numerics, Modula-2 happened around the same *time* as c and has a similar objective, but they *aren't* related. Please don't guess at these things when you don't know the history.

Comment: As I said, Go is not an alternative - it couldn't be used for library or module, accessible from any other language (following C linking standard). The one new player here is Rust - it's compilation model is C/C++ compatible, and it could be used on any side of linking (library/executable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe Google's [Go language](http://golang.org/) will be. At least, that's what I'd expect Google's Go team hopes it will become.

Comment: Yeah Go does seem to be the closest thing I've heard of to a C descendent. The only doubt is its role in embedded space.

Comment: I can hardly believe a language with automatic memory management can sit side by side with C. In fact, I don't believe it. By "side by side" I don't mean performance. I mean semantics.

Comment: If it will succeed I think Google can give quite good progress for GO in embedded space also. ARM is there already.

Comment: @trinithis What makes you not to believe it ? You can have garbage collector for C/C++. Of course it is not supported in runtime, but you can have something kind of that.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan What you mean in any space?

Comment: @trinithis: Good point, automatic garbage collection is very un-Clike

Comment: @trinithis, @Matt: That is why we are talking about evolution. It must not be exactly the same.

Comment: @Incognito: Then just use Java. Otherwise use Ada.

Comment: @Longpoke can't get your point. What you want to say?

Comment: @Incognito: If you want a low level language that's evolved, use Java, but it has garbage collection which introduces nondeterminism, although this a simple fix, just use the real time extensions. Otherwise you can just use Ada which has no GC by default, is much safer than C, and just as fast. In any case, these two languages are evolved compared to C. C also has no safety, which is the only "advantage" of C, and I think that's what OP is trying to find, another language that is nothing more than an abstract assembler (probably because C just sucks.)

Comment: @Icognito, I meant that Matt's concern about Go in the embedded space is somewhat premature as it still has to prove itself in the server, desktop, laptop space... not in terms of capability -- it is definitely a powerful language -- but in terms of traction and popularity.

Comment: @Michael OK, I get it. IMHO it will easily get up on server side... as for desktop I am a little suspicious.

Comment: In 2013, it's interesting to note that Go has more-or-less proven itself in the server and desktop spaces. It's also the most semantically evolved language I've found to date. It's definitely the most worthy successor to C for non-embedded applications. Nondeterminism still forbids it from being used in embedded apps.

Comment: No, Go is *not* like C. In C you can create libraries and reuse from _any_ other language, which is the broadest field for C. In Go you can't.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem with this question and subsequent discussion is that very rarely are languages intended to replace others.  Sure, as you attempted to clarify and defend some of your groupings, they share similar feature sets or accomplish *similar* things, but ultimately, I don't think anybody is going to sit down and write a language that is designed to replace another.  What is far more likely is that language designers want to accomplish a goal and will pick and choose aspects of certain languages that already do that.  For instance, take a look at [Go](http://golang.org/) which is designed to up the ante a bit with regards to ultra-high performance systems programming which, arguably, competes with C a bit.  However, if you look at the FAQ on the mission of the project, they aren't seeking to replace C, but simply augment it and address issues it faces (such as dependency management to name one) (so perhaps this is the answer you're looking for).

So really, whether something is an evolution of something else, depends entirely on the perspective from which you examine and evaluate the evolution.  C++ can be considered an evolution of C because it introduced a new feature set (OO programming) that many consider a step forward in systems design while still retaining a similar syntax and compatibility with C code.  However, it is not entirely an evolution because it is also missing some features that make C a language currently used today.  <strike>No one language can do everything (except for maybe Lisp ;-) I kid, I kid) and never will.</strike> No one language is without tradeoffs. The abstractions that make web development easy are the same abstractions that make low-level systems development impossible (or prohibitively difficult).  So I really think it's hard to say X is an evolution of Y.  Rather, I would say "I want to do W and I know I can use language X but is there something that accomplishes my goals of A, B, and C better?"  Unfortunately programming languages aren't black and white enough to make sweeping statements like that and like every decision you make in programming, it's about trade-offs.

Comment: I already know this. Go is promising as a C alternative.

Comment: Actually, we *did* sit down and design a language specifically to replace C. I believe there are others who designed with the same intent. Ours is a revision of Modula-2, an ideal base for a C replacement, others have started out with C itself. But yes, people do realise that C is a major part of the problem and will need to be replaced. Not by dynamic garbage collecting languages but by something that can replace all or most of what C does for systems implementation, ideally typesafe.

Comment: "No one language can do everything..." I can't agree with that. As far as computers are concerned, to the best of my knowledge, you can do everything with assembly, C, or C++.

Comment: @Andrew you're absolutely right and that was a poorly misstated characterization. What I meant to say is more akin to every language will have pros and cons; strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 5):

The following picture will say more than I could write:

[image: picture]

Comment: More current with 2500 languages http://www.levenez.com/lang/

Comment: Notice the "descendents" of C are C++, C# and Obj-C. Not the languages I'm after.

Comment: @Matt: you haven't said *what* you are after. All you've said is *"I want something that does what c does but isn't c."*

Comment: To be fair, Objective-C is dead and C# is more Java than C.

Answer (score 4):

Pascal would be an equivalent, so would Modula-2.

Mozilla also has a new language called Rust, this is a really nice modern language that is targeted at the same kinds of applications as C/C++

https://www.rust-lang.org/

Comment: Yes, these do seem to be spot on the same paradigm.

Answer (score 4):

C has more than one niche, really.  For low-level systems programming, C replaced platform-specific assembly languages, and nothing has really challenged C in that domain.  C++ would be the only other possible candidate, there (BeOS, many device drivers, etc.).

C was/is also used a lot for high performance numerical code.  In that domain, FORTRAN still has the edge, and there are many other challengers (C++, Matlab, Numpy, Fortress, Scala).

At some level, C is the lowest common denominator that has cross-platform portability.